# Android Login page

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I have written this small login activity in android. It is default first activity to run when app will get started. But when I try to launch the app on my phone, it just crashes . I don't know where is the error coming. I am running it on eclipse. No error is coming. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
  package com.example.ruralaid1;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     String username=null,password=null;

     AutoCompleteTextView user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
     AutoCompleteTextView pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            username = user.getText().toString();
            password =  pwd.getText().toString();

            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(username.equals("") || username.equals(null))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    else if (pwd.equals("") || pwd.equals(null))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password don't match",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            user.setText(null);
                            pwd.setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }

}
```

Comment: Without stack trace then it's difficult to see although clearly the first error stems from user and pwd being initiated outside onCreate. Maybe there are more errors though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the below lines of code after setContentView()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AutoCompleteTextView user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
     AutoCompleteTextView pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);


    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    username = user.getText().toString();
    password = pwd.getText().toString();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (username.equals("") || username.equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username can't be empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (pwd.equals("") || pwd.equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password can't be empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            Menu.class);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username and Password don't match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    user.setText(null);
                    pwd.setText(null);
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
AutoCompleteTextView user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
AutoCompleteTextView pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
```

inside `onCreate(..)` after  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: That is giving an error as I am using it inside onClick() method. So I can't move there.

Comment: @nerdy_me Make it global then `user` and `pwd`

Answer (score 0):

Put these two lines after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
AutoCompleteTextView user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
 AutoCompleteTextView pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
```

code will look like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 String username=null,password=null;

 AutoCompleteTextView user;
 AutoCompleteTextView pwd;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);

        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        username = user.getText().toString();
        password =  pwd.getText().toString();

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(username.equals("") || username.equals(null))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                else if (pwd.equals("") || pwd.equals(null))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password don't match",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        user.setText(null);
                        pwd.setText(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code will be like this

```
 package com.example.ruralaid1;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String username = null, password = null;

AutoCompleteTextView user, pwd;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    user = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    pwd = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);
     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    username = user.getText().toString();
    password = pwd.getText().toString();

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (username.equals("") || username.equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Username can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (pwd.equals("") || pwd.equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Menu.class);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    user.setText(null);
                    pwd.setText(null);
                }
            }
        }
    });


}

 }
```